# Prove that the set of complete & transitive relations on a countably infinite set is uncountable

Tags: real-analysis, relations, infinity

I was going about this by trying to come up with a bijection between this set and the set of all infinite sequences of zeros and ones (like 010100....), which I know in uncountable. But I didn't have much success. Other thoughts on how to get started?

Comment: What is a complete relation?

Comment: For any x and y, either xRy or yRx or both

Comment: So complete implies reflexive? or is it only for distinct x and y?

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to come up with an *injection* from the set of infinite sequences of zeros and ones *into* the set of complete and transitive relations.

So suppose you have a sequence like $(a_n)=(0,1,0,1,0,0,\ldots)$. You want to define a relation $R$ that depends somehow on $(a_n)$. You're going to say that $iRj$ if and only if... [something to do with $a_i$ and $a_j$]. Can you come up with a definition that makes $R$ complete and transitive? And is the mapping from sequences to relations injective?

Comment: I thought about the conditions ai>aj, aj>=aj, ai=aj, ai=aj=0, ai=aj=1. None of them work. Can you please give a further hint?

Comment: Which condition came closest to working? Is it close enough, or is the problem small enough to work around?

Comment: Ok how about I keep the condition ai=aj=0, except that for sequences with ak=0 for exactly one value of k, I take the corresponding relation to be kRw for all w, and not mRn for any other m,n?

Comment: Well, if the condition requires $a_i=a_j$, then whenever $a_i\neq a_j$, we have that $i$ and $j$ are not related by $R$, which means $R$ isn't complete. What about the other conditions?

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Then ai>=aj is the candidate condition. This gives complete & transitive relations, but it isn't an injection because for eg. the relation corresponding to 'all zeros' and 'all ones' is the same..

Comment: Yep, that's what I got too! I believe the "all zeros" and "all ones" are the only two sequences that map to the same relation. So although this mapping isn't quite an injection, you can work around that, either by altering the mapping a bit or altering its domain. For example, the set of all sequences that start with a $0$ is still uncountable.

Comment: Right, got it! Can you please give a reference for the proof that I need only an injection into the set of complete and transitive relations?

Comment: You're asking for a proof that if $f:X\to Y$ is an injection and $X$ is uncountable, then $Y$ is uncountable? That should be in your textbook, but if not, feel free to ask it as a separate question!

Comment: Will look it up, thanks a lot!